# Blender Eevee Transparent Material look different after render

Tags: eevee-render-engine, transparency

I was working on something spent hours to create a good transparent material but when I hit render
it looks different and now I am stuck on this.
it looks fine in viewport but different in render.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a .blend file so we can take a look at your render settings?